Reading file using Spark RDD vs DF
i have a 2MB file, when i read it using
df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").csv("hdfs:///data/ml-100k/u.data", sep="\t")
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()  # returns 1

it reads data in 1 partition, and when I read using
lines = sc.textFile("hdfs:///data/ml-100k/u.data")
lines.getNumPartitions()  # returns 2

it reads data in 2 partitions, what is the reason?

I"m curious how you found out the number of partitions? Can you show the code you used? Please also include some file listing (the number and the size of the files under hdfs:///data/ml-100k/u.data/).

@JacekLaskowski I edited my question & added how i get the number of partitions.
u.data is a 2MB file with 100k lines

Default partition calculation is different for those 2 methods.
sc.textFile():
If you check the implementation of sc.textFile() in git, partition value is by default captured from function defaultMinPartitions which would mostly return 2.
spark.read.csv():
By default this method creates one partition for each block of the file. Since 128MB is default size of a block and your file size is 2MB, since partition will be created.
